# Want to fetch common key and it's multiple values in two hashmaps

Tags: java

I have intialised two hashmaps as below

```
Map<String,List<String>> propertiesMapList1=new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
Map<String,List<String>> propertiesMapList2=new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

and adding a key with multiple values into it.

```
propertiesMapList1.put(srvFld, values);
propertiesMapList2.put(srvFld, values);
```

Im able to fetch the common keys in two hashmaps, how do i get the corresponding values ?

```
Set<String> keysInA = new HashSet<String>(propertiesMapList1.keySet());
Set<String> keysInB = new HashSet<String>(propertiesMapList2.keySet());

// Keys in A and not in B
Set<String> inANotB = new HashSet<String>(keysInA);
inANotB.removeAll(keysInB);

// Keys common to both maps
Set<String> commonKeys = new HashSet<String>(keysInA);
commonKeys.retainAll(keysInB);

Iterator itr = commonKeys.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    System.out.println("common key ::" +itr.next());
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to produce two Maps containing only the common keys and values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Set.retainAll` after creating a new `Set` based on one of the key sets, then get each key for both maps.

```
Map<String,List<String>> map0 =new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
Map<String,List<String>> map1 =new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
map0.put("Foo", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}));
map0.put("Blah", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"d", "e", "f"}));
map1.put("Baz", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"3", "4", "5"}));
map1.put("Blah", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"g", "h", "i"}));

Set<String> retained = new HashSet<String>(map0.keySet());
retained.retainAll(map1.keySet());
for (String k: retained) {
    System.out.printf("In map0: %s%n", map0.get(k));
    System.out.printf("In map1: %s%n", map1.get(k));
}
```

**Output**

```
In map0: [d, e, f]
In map1: [g, h, i]
```

Comment: The OP had already used `retainAll`. Although I remain slightly uncertain if that was his actual question given the simplicity of the step he had missed.

Comment: @OliverMatthews yes it is quite ambiguous, now that you point that out. Will wait for OP's reaction and erase my answer if required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Surely, it's just:

```
Iterator<String> itr = commonKeys.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    String key = itr.next();
    System.out.println("common key ::" + key);
    System.out.println("list1 value ::" + propertiesMapList1.get(key));
    System.out.println("list2 value ::" + propertiesMapList2.get(key));
}
```

Comment: It should be 'Object key' not a String, or you should use Iterator<String>

Comment: Given the `Map<String,List<String>>` declaration, does it?

Comment: You get a compiler error if you don't specify type for the iterator. So either Object key or Iterator<String>

Comment: ah, yes. Java's iterator handling. I was thinking c++.

Comment: You're wrong again ;)

Iterator<String> itr = commonKeys.iterator();

and String key = itr.next();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55761/discussion-between-oliver-matthews-and-sergiy-medvynskyy).